Query that returns all words ignoring one
I have this table with the next records:
CREATE TABLE `t_vias` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`cpro` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`cmum` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
`cpos` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`mun` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
`via` varchar(100) NOT NULL);
 
     
INSERT INTO t_vias VALUES
("6021","28","079","28016","MADRID","GOYA, FRANCISCO DE"),
("6022","28","079","28016","MADRID","FRANCISCO GOYA"),
("6896","28","079","28001","MADRID","GOYA, DE"),
("6897","28","079","28001","MADRID","GOYA (DE)"),
("6900","28","079","28001","MADRID","CALLE GOYA"),
("6901","28","079","28001","MADRID","CALLE DE GOYA");

I receive value "CALLE DE GOYA" from a php variable, and i include in my query the variable value:
SELECT * FROM `t_vias` WHERE via ='CALLE DE GOYA'; 

The result shows only one record:
id  cpro    cmum    cpos    mun     via     
6901    28  079     28001   MADRID  CALLE DE GOYA

Since here, is ok. But if i want show all register with "GOYA" word (remove CALLE, DE, etc):
SELECT * FROM `t_vias` WHERE via ='%GOYA%'; 
 id     cpro    cmum    cpos    mun     via     
6021    28  079     28016   MADRID  GOYA, FRANCISCO DE
6022    28  079     28016   MADRID  FRANCISCO GOYA
6896    28  079     28001   MADRID  GOYA, DE
6897    28  079     28001   MADRID  GOYA (DE)
6900    28  079     28001   MADRID  CALLE GOYA
6901    28  079     28001   MADRID  CALLE DE GOYA

It's ok, return all entries with GOYA.
Trouble is if the value of the variable cames as this: 'DE GOYA'
Then the query:
SELECT * FROM `t_vias` WHERE via LIKE '%DE GOYA%'; 

id  cpro    cmum    cpos    mun     via     
6901    28  079     28001   MADRID  CALLE DE GOYA

Only return one record. How can i search variable value without DE, (DE) if it contains it?

This is a but confusing. Can you show us two sets of data only - sample table data and the expected result. I.e. a [mcve].

See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

I would suggest going to regex
SELECT * FROM `t_vias` WHERE via regexp "GOYA";


Hi @Civette, this is ok with regexp, but in the example, only 'GOYA' and 'GOYA (DE)' are valid results. 'FRANCISCO DE GOYA' is not valid in the result set. What i means that i need all GOYA with 'DE GOYA', 'GOYA DE', 'GOYA, DE?, 'GOYA (DE)' variations that can be in the table, but if there's one 'FRANCISCO DE GOYA' or 'DE GOYA, FRANCISCO', this one is not valid. Thanks a lot.

SELECT * FROM `t_vias` WHERE via LIKE CONCAT('%',REPLACE('DE GOYA', 'DE ', ''), '%');

How about this? You can replace 'DE GOYA' with 'GOYA' or 'GOYA DE'. This will remove DE from DE GOYA -> GOYA and matches that to all records (So it will find GOYA, DE GOYA, GOYA DE, DEGOYADE, GOYADE, etc, etc.
If you need to replace more than just 'DE ', you could look into REGEXP_REPLACE.

Capture the substrings from your [variable], then use simple booleans. How you capture the substrings will depend on what version SQL you're using, but as an example in SQL Server 2017 there is a function called STRING_SPLIT.
SELECT * FROM STRING_SPLIT([variable],' ', 1)

This will return a column of values and an index number (an ordinal), like this:
value ordinal  
DE    1
GOYA  2

Once you have the substrings, by whichever method, you can apply simple boolean math.
WHERE via LIKE [substring1]
   OR (via LIKE [substring1] AND via LIKE [substring2])


WHERE via LIKE '%GOYA%' 
   OR (via LIKE '%GOYA%' AND via LIKE '%DE%')

If you want to exclude FRANCISCO GOYA then just use the piece in parenthesis.
WHERE via LIKE '%GOYA%' AND via LIKE '%DE%'

